# Find minimal A[i]^2 + B[i]^2 when A and B are sorted

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two arrays `A` and `B` length n. `A` is sorted ascending and `B` is sorted descending. Find index `i` for which the "product" `A[i]^2 + B[i]^2` is minimal.

I need a solution in `O(log(n))` which is the desired complexity.

Example case:

```
>>> A
[0, 4, 10, 12, 17, 28, 31, 32, 35, 39]
>>> B
[39, 34, 34, 31, 27, 23, 19, 11, 3, 2]
```

Here the "product" is minimised by i=4

```
>>> [A[i]**2 + B[i]**2 for i in range(10)]
[1521, 1172, 1256, 1105, 1018, 1313, 1322, 1145, 1234, 1525]
>>> min(range(10), key=lambda i: A[i]**2 + B[i]**2)
4
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Also, my first thought is that O(logn) is not possible because you would have to look at every element of each array.

Comment: Linear solution for that problem is easy, as You said. This task is included in binary search bundle, so I thought that O(logn) is desired, but maybe Your argument is true. But why this task is connected with binsearch?

Comment: Maybe there is something special about the fact that A and B are sorted the way they are. Are all the numbers in A and B positive?

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: Hint: I can't remember `A[i]² + B[i]²` being called `product`. How about _sum of squares_? Is the order in `A`  and `B`, respectively, strict? cricket_007 has a valid point: there is one index with A[i]² minimal, one (maybe different) with B[i]² minimal - what happens to the sum "to the outside" of the interval  defined by the two, and what inside?

Comment: Are both arrays of the same length?

Comment: Both arrays must have same length: Otherwise A[i] or B[i] could be undefined for one i in my understanding

Comment: It's true that worst-case complexity is going to be `O(n)`. Can you say anything about the distribution of the sequences? If so, there may be an algorithm whose run time has a better expected value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To formalize Edgar's intuition into an actual cell probe lower bound, consider defining, for `i` in `[1, n]` and some `j` unknown to the algorithm,

```
X[i] = 2 * (n**2 + i)
Y[i] = 2 * (n**2 - i)
A[i] = X[i] + 1 if i == j
       X[i]     if i != j
B[i] = Y[i] + 1 if i == j
       Y[i]     if i != j
```

We do some analysis on `A[i]**2 + B[i]**2` assuming `i != j`.

```
A[i]**2 + B[i]**2 == 4 * n**4 + 8 * n**2 * i + 4 * i**2
                       + 4 * n**4 - 8 * n**2 * i + 4 * i**2
                  == 8 * n**4 + 8 * i**2
                  <= 8 * n**4 + 8 * n**2
```

Now assuming `i == j`.

```
A[i]**2 + B[i]**2 == 8 * n**4 + 8 * n**2 + 8 * i**2 + 2
                  >= 8 * n**4 + 8 * n**2 + 2
```

The latter is *always* greater than the former. (Argh, we wanted a minimum, not a maximum. The idea should be basically the same -- just decrease by one instead of increase by one -- but the algebra is slightly different.)

The family of array pairs with `j` varying look the same except at `j`, so the algorithm must examine half of the indexes on average to determine `j`, which is synonymous for this family to discovering the correct output.

Answer (score 11):

Seems to me that the answer to your question is "NO" and linear algorithm is the fastest.

Constructively we can build sequences of any length which have a maximum in any random place inside such sequence. Also sequences of sums of squares built on these sequences are unordered, so you can't use techniques like binary search which are suitable for sorted sequences.

For example, if we have two arrays of length `7`:

```
5   8   10  11  12  14  15
12  11  10  9   7   6   1
```

we get array of sums of squares like this:

```
169  185  200  202  193  232  225
```

We can see, that the maximum is `232`, but there's no way to find it except of iterating over the whole array cause the sequence of sums of squares is unsorted and maximum lies somewhere inside.

Also using the fact that one array is sorted is useless because second array can impact greatly in total sums and it has no sense to use something like binary search on a single array trying to evaluate total sums.

I'm sure, that this problem is equivalent of finding the largest element in unsorted array which has linear solution as the fastest.

Comment: (same holds for minimum …)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced. That array you gave is unimodal (it increases, then decreases) and there are O(log n)-time algorithms for finding the maximum or minimum element(s) of a unimodal array. If this really is equivalent to searching an unsorted array, you'd need to prove the strong claim that there are no interesting patterns in the result.

Comment: @templatetypedef I enhanced example and array isn't unimodal now

Comment: @templatetypedef I posted adversarial argument with a simple geometric intuition.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple adversarial argument that it's impossible to find the answer without looking at all the points.  That is, the algorithm gives the adversary a possibly adaptive sequence of indexes to check, and the adversary will always fill in an A and B that preserve the monotonicity constraint and it will make it impossible for the algorithm to get the right answer without querying every location.

Consider just the top right quadrant of the 2d plane, for some given N.   The adversary will just stack things on the unit quarter circle, equally spaced in polar coordinates for all but the last query.  Finally, the adversary will put the Nth item queried just barely inside the circle.  Hence this last queried index is the correct answer.  If there are fewer than N queries, and the algorithm picks a queried location, the adversary insists that one remaining unqueried location barely inside the circle, which means the right answer had distance less than 1, but the algorithm returned distance 1.  If instead the algorithm picks an unqueried location, the adversary puts it just outside the circle.